# Fusebox not resolving variables

Tags: apache, coldfusion, fusebox

Ok I'm kind of inheriting a Fusebox applications... It runs on the live server and it runs on the other developers local sys - it DOES NOT resolve variables on MY local system...

I'm set up on Apache - latest release, and CF 9 developer, on a windows system (the live is on Linux and the other developer is on a mac) the sys is on Fusebox 5 (not 5.1 or 5.5)

The reason I know it's not resolving is the URLs come across like this:

```
#request.self#?do=login.xxx&username=#attributes.username#
```

I've requested that the other developer get me his Apache config file - so I can compare - our code base is identical - as we check out the same SVN source, and the Fusebox files are identical - we confirmed that this morning...

Can anyone point me in a direction - because I'm stymied....

Comment: So you're seeing the actual cf tags and variables if you view source, right?  You definitely have a set up issue.  Have you tried the site with the built in server (its at 127.0.0.1:8500)

Comment: no i have not - but it's not that it's not resolving variables at all...it's only in the URL, such when they pass vars via a redirect...

Comment: are you getting pound signs in the URL?

Comment: yup - that's the issue (I ran into this in '06 - but I can't remember the solution).

Comment: Can you share some code?  It's definitely something having to do with missing cfoutputs in for the url handlers or similar - probably in some weird fuseboxy SES implementation.

Comment: Nate - fusebox is supposed to take care of resolving those - I haven't touched the core files - and the code works fin on two other boxes - however here is a code snippet...

<fuseaction name="ValidateAccountHolder">
 <if condition="[conditions]">
  <false>
   <relocate url="#request.self#?do=login.logout&amp;timeout=true&amp;#request.currentpageFB#" />
  </false>
 </if>
</fuseaction>

Comment: im certian it's a cong fig issue - but I done even know where to look... Apache, CF, FBox...?

Comment: ANSWER - I found the CF debug options in the CF administrator were 'somehow' interfering with the fusebox URL generation.... turning off robust debug FIXED the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [configuration tool](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/configuring_07.html#1123947) to compare the webroot mappings or check the [httpd.conf](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/setup_dev.html) to compare the [DocumentRoot](http://www.sitepoint.com/install-coldfusion-mx-windows/) and [AddType](http://adminsgoodies.com/running-coldfusion-commands-inside-an-html-file/) mappings.